# In HTML, what is the advantage of using divs over using tables?

Tags: html, html-table

After years of working on the backend algorithmic and analytic stuff, I have recently been forced to do some "HTML work". (And you guys have something called jQuery now, is that right?)  Anyhoo, back when I used to do HTML (prior to XHTML days), tables were very very common.  Now, I see a deluge of support for "div"s and honorifics such as "table-less!".  To catch up on the years that I missed, what is the reason that divs are preferred over tables?  [I recently tried to do a simple two column table (66%,33%) into divs, and the bruises are still fresh.]

I realize that the question may be subjective, so as a specific subquestion: **What is the easy and concise div based HTML that renders the following table**:

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td width="33%">Name</td>
         <td width="67%">Description</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>National Hockey League</td>
         <td>A much longer paragraph about the league</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A big reason is that you want the HTML markup to define the "structure" of the document, and the CSS to define the "look and feel". A <table> element should represent a table of information, rather than a quick way to get a desired layout. That being said, the new grid and flexbox layout options available in CSS3 will make all this a *lot* easier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tables shouldn't be used for page layouts because they are:

- Slow to render as the browser needs to download most, if not all of the table to render it properly
- They require more HTML then non-table layouts which means slower loading and rendering as well as increased bandwidth usage
- They can be a nightmare to maintain as they can get complex quickly
- They can break text copying
- They negatively affect screenreaders and may make your cone\tent inaccessible to some users
- They are not as flexible as using proper semantic markup
- They were never intended to be used for page layouts

Comment: And how about the specific question - how to render a simple 2 col table using divs?

Comment: @AmrinderArora You asked multiple questions, however John's answer best addresses your question, as it is stated in the question title (and again in the body).

Comment: @Madbreaks The subquestion is really an "instance" of the question.  For example, John's response says that table based code can be nightmare to maintain.  From that I infer that div based code is easy to maintain.  The answer to subquestion would serve as a great example for that.

Comment: +1 for the screenreader bit. Also referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399530/why-table-is-not-good-for-layout-while-div-is-for-screen-reader-users

Answer (score 2):

If you're rendering tabular data, by all means use tables - that's what they're intended for.  Your example probably qualifies!  But don't use tables to create page structure for the many reasons provided in John Conde's answer.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  If I understand this, tables started getting used for a lot of layout reasons, and the divs are right way to do that, I agree.  Also, I gather that it is not that the tables are considered evil (thank god for that!), it is just that their overuse is.  Do I have it right?

Comment: Correct.  To be more specific though (not to beat a dead horse) it is using them to define page layout/structure that is considered evil.  And FWIW don't let anyone tell you that doing div-based layouts is easier, because it's not.  But you *will* get used to it (we all do).  As mentioned elsewhere CSS3 helps tremendously.

Comment: Thanks again.  If I could see the div based code for that table, my getting used to part might just begin.  Might be able to close the question as well!

Comment: I'd counter - why create a div-based representation of a table?  Just use a table!  What we're discussing is layouts, and why you shouldn't use tables for layouts.

Answer (score 0):

With modern HTML standards; tables should only be used for displaying tabular data; 
http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm